# Having problems writing mysql query joining 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query (which partially works) looking like the following:

```
SELECT i.vehicle_id, i.user_id, i.make, i.model, i.year, i.state, i.price, i.class, i.fuel, i.mileage, i.mileage_type, i.featured, i.published, i.creation, i.status, m.vehicle_id, m.type, m.src, a.user_id, a.inventory_status, a.country, s.user_id, s.currency_iso, s.currency_code 
FROM `cms_dealer_inventory` AS `i`, 
`cms_dealer_inventory_media` AS `m`, 
`cms_dealer_account` AS `a`, 
`cms_dealer_setting` AS `s` 
WHERE i.make='chevrolet' 
AND i.model='camaro' 
AND i.year='2014' 
AND (i.mileage <= 200000 ) 
AND i.published='1' 
AND a.inventory_status='1' 
AND m.vehicle_id=i.vehicle_id 
AND m.type='exterior' 
AND a.user_id=i.user_id 
AND s.user_id=i.user_id 
AND a.country='DE' 
GROUP BY i.vehicle_id 
ORDER BY i.featured DESC, i.price ASC, i.state DESC, i.make ASC
```

The problem is, the `cms_dealer_inventory_media` may or may not contain images (bind by vehicle_id). I know the problem is with my WHERE statement in which I am specifically saying `m.vehicle_id=i.vehicle_id AND m.type='exterior'` but, it causes entries with no images to be ignore.
What I need is a query which makes the `m.vehicle_id=i.vehicle_id` run IF there are results to `cms_dealer_inventory_media`.

Comment: Don't join tables just by listing them with commas.  Use the actual `join` syntax.

Comment: Left join should do the trick

Comment: Also in addition to using the actual `join` syntax, here you will want to use `left join` for the table where the data might not exist.

Comment: Hello Jay, thanks for the reply. Yes, I've tried that too. Same result. I know for a fact that is possible to achieve what I'm aiming for but, it seems what I will have to make 2 queries and a look to add the results to the first query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `left join`

```
SELECT i.vehicle_id, i.user_id, i.make, i.model, i.year, i.state, i.price, i.class, i.fuel, i.mileage, i.mileage_type, i.featured, i.published, i.creation, i.status, m.vehicle_id, m.type, m.src, a.user_id, a.inventory_status, a.country, s.user_id, s.currency_iso, s.currency_code 
FROM `cms_dealer_inventory` AS `i` left join
`cms_dealer_inventory_media` AS `m` on m.vehicle_id=i.vehicle_id 
AND m.type='exterior' left join
`cms_dealer_account` AS `a` on a.inventory_status='1' 
AND a.user_id=i.user_id AND a.country='DE' left join
`cms_dealer_setting` AS `s` ON s.user_id=i.user_id  

WHERE i.make='chevrolet' 
AND i.model='camaro' 
AND i.year='2014' 
AND (i.mileage <= 200000 ) 
AND i.published='1' 
GROUP BY i.vehicle_id 
ORDER BY i.featured DESC, i.price ASC, i.state DESC, i.make ASC
```

Comment: the above returns: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`cms_dealer_setting` AS `s` ON s.user_id=i.user_id

Comment: @Jay sorry forgot one `left join`

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks so much! It's working properly now.

Comment: Just a quick note to anyone having the same problem, the solution provided by @Mureinik also works perfectly as does this one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you change your query to use the more modern explicit `joins`, you could use `left join`s:

```
SELECT i.vehicle_id, i.user_id, i.make, i.model, i.year, i.state, i.price, i.class, i.fuel, i.mileage, i.mileage_type, i.featured, i.published, i.creation, i.status, m.vehicle_id, m.type, m.src, a.user_id, a.inventory_status, a.country, s.user_id, s.currency_iso, s.currency_code 
FROM `cms_dealer_inventory` AS `i`
LEFT JOIN `cms_dealer_inventory_media` AS `m` ON m.vehicle_id=i.vehicle_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_dealer_account` AS `a` ON a.user_id=i.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_dealer_setting` AS `s` ON s.user_id=i.user_id 
WHERE i.make='chevrolet' 
AND i.model='camaro' 
AND i.year='2014' 
AND (i.mileage <= 200000 ) 
AND i.published='1' 
AND a.inventory_status='1' 
AND m.type='exterior' 
AND a.country='DE' 
GROUP BY i.vehicle_id 
ORDER BY i.featured DESC, i.price ASC, i.state DESC, i.make ASC
```

Comment: Your join wouldn't work, because `a`and 'm' is used in `where` statement

Comment: You can use properties from joined tables in the `where` clause.

Comment: @Mureinik Yes you can but you get not the records, where `a` or `m` has no record.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the join properly

in your case you need all the records from cms_dealer_inventory

so join will be `cms_dealer_inventory` left outer `cms_dealer_inventory_media`